# How to fix Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.?

Tags: solidity, javascript, nodejs

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.7.0;

contract Adoption {
  address[16] public adopters;
 function getAdopters() public view returns(address[16]) {
   return adopters;

 }
 function adopt(uint petId) public returns(uint) {
   require(petId>=0 && petId<=15,"oops");
   adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
   return petId;

 }

}
```

The above script is showing me the below errors.

1.`address[16]` used in line 5 shows

```
Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
```

What is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
returns(address[16])
```

To this:

```
returns(address[16] memory)
```